# Secure monitor to desk (from falling)

Tags: technology

I want to prevent a computer monitor from falling, if the desk's legs are kicked or anything similar. The desk is relatively light.

I thought of simply drilling a hole through the base of the monitor and the desk and securing it that way. But besides being unsightly, I'm not sure that monitor bases are built for that kind of stress (if the desk is kicked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Spring Clamp on the back of the stand to hold it to the desk:
[image: Spring Clamp]

These are ridiculously cheap to buy and they are useful in all sorts of ways.

If this won't work for some reason, you could basically adhere the stand to the desk by pressing a huge amount of blu-tack into the base and pressing it hard to the desk.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is "how to secure a monitor to a desk", but I believe the actual question should be "How do I prevent my monitor from falling off the desk". One solution would be to attach it to the desk. But another solution is to prevent the desk from being kicked.

You may be able to accomplish this by placing things on the floor around the legs, such as a potted plant on the floor. You could also place the table against a wall, and put the back of a couch against one side.  (No one will walk through the couch!)

Another option is to get a more solid, heavy table that would move very little if accidentally kicked. You could even reinforce your existing table to add weight to it.

A final option is to place the table against a wall, and mount the monitor to that wall. It could be just a centimeter above the tabletop so it is still at an ergonomic height for viewing.

Comment: +1. Though I'm still looking for a simple hack without changing the requirements.

Comment: @ispiro Thank you. I completely understand. I tried to come up with a solution, but I kept thinking about building a large structure around the monitor and attaching that structure to the table. That solution is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Epoxy Putty Monitor Anchors on Imgur]

There are 2 epoxy putty brackets, handshaped. I put plastic wrap on monitor stand during shaping so putty would not leave residue. Epoxy hardens in minutes. Then plastic wrap can be removed. C-clamped for easy moving, but could be screwed down.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3TkWmF8fga3NjhwbnhiaWpDSms

Answer (score 1):

Best easy and cheap solution is to find flat type thick ribbon/rope and nail to desk.
[image: flat thick ribbon/rope]

We have ships and as you guessed we have trouble with waves.Our Crew on board found a solution for fixing notebooks,computers even monitors to desks.It is also easy to remove if you want ; and you can find them from anywhere.

Also we used a professional solution for our general manager maybe you may be interested for that solution too here is the  product we used :[image: ergotron's solution]

I hope it helps

Comment: I searched google with Cotton Flat Tape I found [this link](https://www.etsy.com/listing/281533454/10-yd-91-mt-soft-beige-cotton-flat-tape?ref=related-2) may be you can find more.

Answer (score 1):

There are some semi-sticky gel pads, if you put them on a table, they stick to the table surface, can be easily removed without a trace by gently pulling for a couple of seconds, but if you try yanking it off quickly, that is really hard. I saw such things in Japan used for that very purpose (preventing monitors etc. falling off desks during earthquakes): just put 3~4 of them between the monitor base and the desk surface. Don't know how they are called in English (or in any other language, for that matter), just google for something like "earthquake gel pads/shock proof pads".

Comment: This looks really good! [Here](https://www.amazon.com/Quakehold-22111-Glass-Crystal-Clear/dp/B0000V0720)'s a link I found. Thanks.